# Thread class closing from other Class (Activity) with protected void onStop() Android

Tags: android, multithreading, class

I have a Problem with Closing the Thread. I will Closing the Thread with onStop,onPause and onDestroy. This is my Source in the Activity Class:

```
   @Override
protected void onStop(){
   super.onStop();
   finish();
} 

@Override
protected void onPause()  { 
     super.onPause(); 
     finish();
    } 

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
        this.mWakeLock.release();
        super.onDestroy();
}
```

And the Thread Class:

```
public class GameThread extends Thread {

private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
private Handler mHandler;
private Context mContext;
private Paint mLinePaint;
private Paint blackPaint;

//for consistent rendering
private long sleepTime;
//amount of time to sleep for (in milliseconds)
private long delay=1000/30;
//state of game (Running or Paused).
int state = 1;
public final static int RUNNING = 1;
public final static int PAUSED = 2;
public final static int STOPED = 3;

GameSurface gEngine;

public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context, Handler handler,GameSurface gEngineS){

    //data about the screen
    mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    mHandler = handler;
    mContext = context;
    gEngine=gEngineS;
}

//This is the most important part of the code. It is invoked when the call to start() is
//made from the SurfaceView class. It loops continuously until the game is finished or
//the application is suspended.
private long beforeTime;
@Override
public void run() {

    //UPDATE
    while (state==RUNNING) {
        Log.d("State","Thread is runnig");
        //time before update
        beforeTime = System.nanoTime();
        //This is where we update the game engine
        gEngine.Update();

        //DRAW
        Canvas c = null;
        try {
            //lock canvas so nothing else can use it
            c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                //clear the screen with the black painter.
                //reset the canvas
                c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                //This is where we draw the game engine.
                gEngine.doDraw(c);
            }
        } finally {
            // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
            // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
            // inconsistent state
            if (c != null) {
                mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }



        this.sleepTime = delay-((System.nanoTime()-beforeTime)/1000000L);

        try {
            //actual sleep code
            if(sleepTime>0){
                this.sleep(sleepTime);

            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GameThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        while (state==PAUSED){
            Log.d("State","Thread is pausing");
            try {
                this.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

How i can close the Thread from Activity Class??

Answer (score 0):

you could define a currentState variable as a static variable and then you could access it by static functions to change it's state  to something witch could stop or pause your thread but i think you can use Android's internal components which are most suitable for this kind of works like Services which you could Send them a Message or it could be send back message to your activity or you cans you AsyncTask . take a look at [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)